# __rand__ across np array dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vector, vectorization

How to compare values in `val` against `arr` based on operators `o`?

```
import numpy as np
from operator import gt, lt

val = np.array([[3,7,1], [4,8,5], [5,10,3]])
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [9,7,5,3,1]])
o = (gt, gt, lt)

# [3,7,1]
# (3 gt [1,2,3,4,5]) & (7 gt [6,7,8,9,10] & (1 lt [9,7,5,3,1])
# [True, True, False, False, False] & [True, False, False, False, False] & [True, True, True, True, False]
# => [True, False, False, False, False]

# [4,8,5]
# (4 gt [1,2,3,4,5]) & (8 gt [6,7,8,9,10] & (5 lt [9,7,5,3,1])
# => [True, True, False, False, False]

# [5,10,3]
# (5 gt [1,2,3,4,5]) & (10 gt [6,7,8,9,10]) & (3 lt [9,7,5,3,1])
# => [True, True, True, False, False]

result = np.array([[True, False, False, False, False],
                   [True, True, False, False, False],
                   [True, True, True, False, False]])
```

For each `val_i`, operator `o_j` is applied between `val_i_j` and all elements in `arr_j`. The resulting vectors are compared with `__rand__`.

Current solution seems too difficult.

```
out = []
for i in range(len(val)):
    m = o[0](val[i][0], arr[0])
    print(val[i][0], m)
    for j in range(len(o)):
        if j > 0:
            m &= o[j](val[i][j], arr[j])
            print(val[i][j], m)
    out.append(list(mask))
```

Comment: The logic is unclear due to the `...` can you provide the full explicit calculation of, say, the first `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np

val = np.array([[3,7,1], [4,8,5], [5,10,3]])
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [9,7,5,3,1]])
o = (np.greater, np.greater, np.less)

out = np.logical_and.reduce([o[i](val[:, i, None], arr[i]) for i in range(len(o))])
print(out)
```

It gives:

```
[[ True False False False False]
 [ True  True False False False]
 [ True  True  True False False]]
```